# Cardinality of sets and union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I ve been thinking about this lately, but couldn t come up with an answers.Let A and B be two infinite  sets of the same cardinality, is it true that the union of A and B has the same cardinality as A and B?

Comment: not necessarily true if $A$ and $B$ are finite

Comment: For the finite case, if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then you have $|A\cup B| = |A|+|B|$ and more generally for not necessarily disjoint $A$ and $B$ that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$.  You would have for the finite case that $|A\cup B|=|A|$ would imply that $A=B=A\cup B$

Comment: Right, sorry, obviously, for the finite case it s false. I was thinking of the infinite case. If they are both countable it s true, and I think it s true if they both have the same cordiality as R. But I don t know what happens for arbitrary infinite sets

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming the axiom of choice it is true. Without the axiom of choice there can be counterexamples. In particular, if $A$ is an [amorphous set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set), let $A_0=A\times\{0\}$ and $A_1=A\times\{1\}$. Clearly there is a bijection between $A_0$ and $A_1$, but if there were a bijection between $A_0\cup A_1$ and $A$, $A$ would be the disjoint union of two infinite sets and therefore not amorphous.

Comment: Awesome. So assuming choice, could you give some details of how the proof goes? Or a reference would be welcome

Comment: @ham_ham01: Theorem B$3$ in [this PDF](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/real-an/ap-b-card.pdf) gives a proof using Zorn’s lemma, which is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: Thank you. Very much appreciated

Comment: @ham_ham01: You’re welcome.